# Blazor automatic login for Active Directory users

Tags: authentication, active-directory, blazor

I'm trying to develop a Blazor server application that will be used by users from the company domain and users outside of the company domain

I would like to avoid asking for user and password for users in the active directory domain, those should be logged in automatically and I should be able to get username, surname and email from active directory.

The other users instead should be presented with the usual login page that ask for a user and password

This was possible back in the day with regular asp.net applications hosted in IIS, but how can I do that with blazor?

The app will be hosted on IIS